# Adding JavaScript Command to a buttom in an existing template in Magento

Tags: javascript, html, css, magento

I'm using a 3rd Party Checkout and I want over override there login feature with a custom login.

Here is the code that I am working with in Magento.

```
<?php echo $this->getMessagesBlock()->getGroupedHtml() ?>
<p class="left"><a class="login-trigger signin-modal" data-modal="modal-login"><?php echo $this->__('LOGIN')?></a></p>

<script type="text/javascript">

//<![CDATA[
    var dataForm1 = new VarienForm('login-form', true);
    //]]>
```

> 

I want to point this button to javascript:socialLogin()

I'm sure this is something simple, but I'm a little rusty

https://www.acuity-sports.com/onepage/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<a class="login-trigger signin-modal" data-modal="modal-login" onclick="socialLogin();"><?php echo $this->__('LOGIN')?></a>
```

I have just checked it in your site. It works fine.

Comment: Thanks...  For the life of me I couldn't think of the command I needed to use.

Answer (score 0):

using jquery:

```
jQuery('.login-trigger').click(function(){
    socialLogin();
})
```